# dimple.js Show X Axis label, but if "value" is null don't place a circle on chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

Question: How do I show the Date Value on the X Axis, but not show the circle in the chart area if it is null?

So I am playing around with Dimple.js and I have created a PHP function that pulls data from my MySql database, and maps out when certain trucks arrived to a location by hours.  So the X Axis is the date and the Y Axis is the military time it arrived.  I use the Min date and max date as the begin and end to loop through.  I want to show each day between min and max on the x axis, so if no trucks arrived I assign Value = Null for that.

The problem is there are now circles on the bottom of my chart along the 0 section of the y axis for these nulls.  I don't know how to check if value is zero don't show the circle, but still show the date on the X Axis.  The data is structured as below:

```
$dataset_progress005[] = array('Date' => $truck_arrive_day,
      'Value' => $truck_arrive_time,
      'Move ID' => $move_inbound_time_id);
```

with the javascript as this....

```
<script type="text/javascript"> <!--Example Plot Chart....-->
        var svg = dimple.newSvg("#area_progress_report5", 800, 400);

        var data = <?php echo json_encode($dataset_progress005); ?>;

        var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
        myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 505, 305)
        var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Date");
        //var x = myChart.addTimeAxis("x", "Date");
        //var x = myChart.addMeasureAxis("x", "Date");
        x.addOrderRule("Date");
        myChart.addCategoryAxis("y", "Value");
        myChart.addSeries("Move ID", dimple.plot.bubble);
        myChart.draw();

        x.shapes.selectAll("text").attr("transform",
            function (d) {
              return d3.select(this).attr("transform") + " translate(0, 40) rotate(-90)";
            });

     </script>
```

Question: How do I show the Date Value on the X Axis, but not show the circle in the chart area if it is null?

Comment: For lines, D3 has a function [`.defined()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-line_defined) that allows you to specify where it shouldn't be drawn, but dimple doesn't seem to expose that. It also looks like you can't use different data for chart and axes, so my guess is that you would need to either go pure D3 or hack the source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at this, dimple doesn't currently support null values quite as it should.  If there is a null in your data it will fail the check for a numeric field and treat it as a string field, which means when you use it for a measure axis you will get a distinct count of values rather than an aggregate total.  I will fix that in the code base but in the meantime - if you are able to treat nulls as zero in your dataset - you can hide them after drawing:

```
...
chart.draw();
series.shapes.style("opacity", function (d) {
    return (d.yValue === 0 ? 0 : 0.8);
});
```

Here's a fiddle to show what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/GeLng/2/

Edit, I've just noticed you are doing 2 category axes which changes it a bit.  You can still remove the bubble and you can treat it as null, you don't need to worry about converting to zero, but I'm not sure of a way to avoid there being a null space on the y axis:

http://jsfiddle.net/GeLng/3/

Comment: John.  Thanks for the update.  I plugged a subset of my data into your fiddle and updated it here:  http://jsfiddle.net/GeLng/6/ but I am still having the issue of the null value showing up.  See for example 8/24/2013 is showing a point on that day as null.  Also, I'm trying to figure out how to make the y axis only show "major" times.....for example 1, 2, 3....not 1:01, 1:04, 2, etc

Comment: The reason the bubble is showing, is your data includes empty strings rather than null values, this just requires a change in the if statement.  Here's a version fixing this: http://jsfiddle.net/GeLng/7/ regarding the y axis, you need a time axis to deal with time in that manner (which also removes the null bar) here's a fiddle showing how to configure the time axis: http://jsfiddle.net/GeLng/9/

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you so much John Kiernander.